# Porting a PowerBuilder Application to .NET

Tags: c#, .net, migration, powerbuilder, powerbuilder-conversion

Does anyone have any advice for migrating a PowerBuilder 10 business application to .NET?

My company is considering migrating a legacy PB application to .NET (C#) and I am just wondering if anyone has any experience - good or bad - that you would like to share.

The application is rather large with 10 PBL libraries, some PFC as well as custom frameworks. There are a large number of DLL calls being made as well. Finally, it uses a Microsoft SQL Server database.

We have discussed porting the "core" application code to .NET and then porting more advanced functionality across as-needed.

Comment: To the sales people whose companies sell PB-to-.NET migration services - please do not post advertisements to this thread or attempt to contact me directly. I am not interested in purchasing your services. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Justin - just curious of what ending up happening here? It's been awhile since your original post. I'd be interested in hearing if you have a couple minutes to share. We're looking at a PB 11.5 app that we're being asked to migrate to .net :) Thanks! Bill

Comment: @Bill - Unfortunately, nothing really happened. I actually have switched jobs in the meantime, but last I knew there was an early effort to develop a new system, but it was going to be a whole new engineering effort which would not include a PB migration. Anyway,  best of luck to you on your efforts.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

When I saw the title, I was just going to lurk, being a renowned PB bigot. Oh well. Thanks for the vote of confidence, Bernard.

My first suggestion would be to ditch the language of self-deception. If I eat half of a "lite" cheesecake, I'm still going to lose sight of my belt. A migration can take as little as 10 minutes. What you'll be doing is a *rewrite*. The **time** needs to be measured as a rewrite. The **risk** needs to be measured as a rewrite. And the **design effort** should be measured as a rewrite.

Yes, I said design effort. "Migrate" conjures up images of pumping code through some black box with a translation mirroring the original coming out the other side. Do you want to replicate the same design mistakes that were made back in 1994 that you've been *living with* for years? Even with excellent quality code, I'd guess that excellent design choices in PowerBuilder may be awful design choices in C#. Does a straight conversion neglect the power and strengths of the platform? Will you be *living with* the consequences of neglecting a good C# design for the next 15 years?

---

That rant aside, since you don't mention your motivation for moving "to .NET," it's hard to suggest what options you might have to mitigate the risk of a rewrite. If your management has simply decided that PowerBuilder developers smell bad and need to be expunged from the office, then good luck on the rewrite.

If you simply want to deploy Windows Forms, Web Forms, Assemblies or .NET web services, or to leverage the .NET libraries, then as Paul mentioned, moving to 11.0 or 11.5 could get you there, with an effort closer to a migration. (I'd suggest again reviewing and making sure you've got a good design for the new platform, particularly with Web Forms, but that effort should be significantly smaller than a rewrite.) If you want to deploy a WPF application, I know a year is quite a while to wait, but looking into PowerBuilder 12 might be worth the effort. Pulled off correctly, the WPF capability may put PowerBuilder into a unique and powerful position.

If a rewrite is guaranteed to be in your future (showers seem cheaper), you might want to phase the conversion. DataWindow.NET makes it possible to to take your DataWindows with you. (My pet theory of the week is that PowerBuilder developers take the DataWindow for granted until they have to reproduce all the functionality that comes built in.) Being able to drop in pre-existing, pre-tested, multi-row, scrollable, minimal resource consuming, printable, data-bound dynamic UI, generating minimal SQL with built-in logical record locking and database error conversion to events, into a new application is a big leg up.

You can also phase the transition by converting your PowerBuilder code to something that is consumable by a .NET application. As mentioned, you can produce COM objects with the PB 10 you've got, but will have to move to 11.0 or 11.5 to produce assemblies. The value of this may depend on how well partitioned your application is. If your business logic snakes through GUI events and functions instead of being partitioned out to non-visual objects (aka custom classes), the value of this may be questionable. Still, this is a design *faux pas* that should probably be fixed before a full conversion to C#; this is something that can be done while still maintaining the PowerBuilder application as a preliminary step to a phased and then a full conversion.

No doubt I'd rather see you stay with PowerBuilder. Failing that, I'd like to see you succeed. Just remember, once you take that first bite, [you'll have to finish it](http://www.supersizedmeals.com/food/images/articles/20061215-Heart_Attack_Grill_2.jpg).

Good luck finding that belt,

Terry.

---

I see you've mentioned moving "core components" to .NET to start. As you might guess by now, I think a staged approach is a wise decision. Now the definition of "core" may be debatable, but how about a contrary point of view. Food for thought? (Obviously, this was the wrong week to start a diet.) Based on where PB is right now, it would be hard to divide your application between PB and C# along application functionality (e.g. Accounts Receivable in PB, Accounts Payable in C#). A division that may work is GUI vs business logic. As mentioned before, pumping business logic out of PB into executables C# can consume is already possible. How about building the GUI in C#, with the DataWindows copied from PB and the business logic pumped out as COM objects or assemblies? Going the other way, to consume .NET assemblies in PB, you'll either have to move up to 11.x and migrate to Windows Forms, or put them in a [COM callable wrapper](http://pbdj.sys-con.com/node/258395).

Or, just train your C# developers in PowerBuilder. This just may be a rumour, but I hear the new PowerBuilder marketing tag line will be "So simple, even a C# developer can use it." ;-)

Comment: Wow, thank you for such a detailed answer! We are still in the early phases of determining whether a rewrite is feasible. I suppose you are right - I need to be honest about this from the get-go as it will be a huge effort to rewrite our application, if that is the path ultimately taken. 

Our main motivation in moving to .NET is that the developers here have much more .NET experience than with PB, although I agree that it is easy to take the DataWindow's strengths for granted.

Anyway, thanks again for your insight.

Comment: Outstanding post Terry. Sorry to put you on the spot, but I've appreciated all the great things PB you've done and knew you'd posted in other PB questions on SO. And your pet theory isn't a theory, it's reality. Almost everyone I talk to discounts PB for Java or .Net. It sucks not to be able to take advantage of the tools Java and .Net have, but PB is still powerful and people don't appreciate how many apps are still running on it. If only so many PB implementations didn't misuse its power and flexibility!

Comment: Nice answer Terry.  I have invested many hours in keeping abreast in new technologies and it is my humble opinion PB still takes the cake for best too to build the standard business app, Microsoft is getting close with ASP.NET MVC3 and use of a good object repository method, but this isn't what the OP asked so I apologize.  Moving from PB to .NET is a going to end up being a re-design, and most shops I've seen tend to break off pieces that are better suited towards the web, for example workflow functionality. It won't be easy so definitely take a hard look at the reasons you want to migrate.

Answer (score 6):

I think gbjbaanb gave you a good answer above.

Some other questions worth considering:

- Is this PB10 app a new, well-written PB10 app, or was it one made in 1998 in PB4, then gradually converted to PB10 over the years? A well-written app should have some decent segregation between the business logic and the GUI, and you should be able to systematically port your code to .Net. At least, it should be a lot easier than if this is a legacy PB app, in which case it would be likely that you'd have tons of logic buried in buttons, datawindows, menus, and who knows what else. Not impossible, but more difficult to rework.
- How well is the app running? If it's OK and stable, and doesn't need a lot of new features, then maybe it doesn't need rewriting. Or, as gbjbaanb said, you can put .Net wrappers around some pieces and then expose the functionality you need without a full rewrite. If, on the other hand, your app is cantankerous, nasty, not really satisfying business needs, and is making your users inefficient, then you might have a case for rewriting, or perhaps some serious refactoring and then some enhancements. There are PB guys serving sentences, er, I mean, making a living with the second scenario.

I'm not against rewrites if the software is exceedingly poor and is negatively affecting the company's business, but even then gradual adjustments and improvements are a less risky way to achieve system evolution.

Also, don't bail on this thread until after Terry Voth posts. He's on StackOverflow and is one of the top PB guys.

Answer (score 4):

If its rather large, you might have better results writing a front-end for it in .net (or a web-based GUI) and using that to interact with your PB code, assuming you can expose the functionality it as an API.

If you're using PB 9 or greater, you can generate COM or .NET dlls, that you can then consume by a C# GUI. I'd recommend this over a rewrite in any new language.

Remember, rewrites are never a silver bullet, they always end up more time-consuming, difficult, and buggy than you first expect.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to spend some time investigating [PowerBuilder 11.5](http://www.sybase.com:80/products/modelingdevelopment/powerbuilder) (recently released) which adds some significant .NET integration.

Migrating to PowerBuilder 11.5 in order to make use of new .NET code will certainly be a lot easier than completely rewriting the entire app in C#.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it's good or not but check this (commercial) product  :  [PB.Net](http://www.felix.fr/produits/PBNet/PBNet.cfm)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Another person on the team actually just discovered this as well. Its a shame there is not more information about it or a free demo/trial version available, but it sounds promising.

Answer (score 3):

> > My pet theory of the week is that PowerBuilder developers take the DataWindow for granted until they have to reproduce all the functionality that comes built in.

I'd back that theory.  I went though an attempted conversion from PB8 to Java on a project several years ago that failed miserably, even using the first-gen HTML DataWindow.  My current employer is hell-bent on moving to C#, not using Datawindow.NET despite > 2K DWOs in our current product.  I'm not looking forward to the day when the realization sets in.  (the entire product consist of several user applications, more than a dozen services, and use about 70 PBDs)

OP - unless your application is unusually well-structured (originally written for EA Server maybe?), this will not be a port.  Things work too differently in the PB & .NET environments for a plain port to work satisfactorily.  I cannot stress this enough - if you're really using the PB event model, a "port" will likely be a failure.

You need to look at logic flow (intertwined UI & process), control flow (who owns the process or data *right now*), data access (UI, data layer, ??) and the parts of the DW event model you're using from code.  If you're thinking about ASP.NET (as we are), your whole user interaction experience will have to change, and that will feed back into the other considerations.

Not directly related to code, build automation will change (we use PowerGen for consistent PB builds; MSBuild is very different) as will your installation & setup.

Answer (score 3):

I think anyone considering this for a large app would be pretty crazy not to very seriously consider using the DataWindow.NET, so as not to lose their investment in the DWs.

Answer (score 3):

PHB's at major corporations think that Powerbuilder is a toy language and migrating to a new language like C# is trivial and can be done at a low cost.  In fact, migrating a PB application to any other language will cost at least as much as developing an entirely new application on the new language.  The resulting app will generally lose functionality compared to the original and will result in user dissatisfaction.  I have seen a number of attempts - all have failed because of the difficulty and the user issues.

If it ain't broke, don't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it`s doable now without rewriting service components period.

PB 12.5>

And target GUI and service component migrations and integrations to c#.

Migration/Integration strategy may vary depending your project scope, scalability, resources and timeline.

You can use these target and project types in PowerBuilder .NET.
Refer this link [Sybase_PB .Net](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc37772.1250/html/pbgs/CHDFGFBFAWF.htm)

- WPF Window Application   WPF Window Application, WCF Client Proxy, or REST Client Proxy
- PB Assembly  WCF Client Proxy, REST Client Proxy, or PB Assembly
- .NET Assembly    WCF Client Proxy, REST Client Proxy, or .NET Assembly
- WCF Service  WCF Client Proxy, REST Client Proxy, or WCF Service